# How to invoke function once the dom element style is changed Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have gone through multiple examples, and implemented the same behavior what the example has stated.

Once the page is loaded, if there is a change in the styling of the dom element I need to trigger a method.

Even if I change anything in the browser console, then also the style change event should trigger. the event will be on display none and display block.

In my code, if am changing in the browser console then the change method is not getting triggered.

This is what I tried:

```js
(function() {
    var ev = new $.Event('style'),
        orig = $.fn.css;
    $.fn.css = function() {
        var ret = orig.apply(this, arguments);
        $(this).trigger(ev);
        return ret;
    }
})();


$('p').bind('style', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).attr('style'));
});
```

```css
p {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> test </p>
```

Comment: how are you `changing in the browser console` - using jquery .css? because your code seems to work just fine (though, I didn't try with jquery 1.11)

Comment: Use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: @JaromandaX: No am changing in the css style properties, it should work with jquery.css as well as changing the style property

Comment: @trincot: Can you please help me out with the demo of the same code what I posted

Comment: no it shouldn't, because all you've done is intercepted jquery .css method - nothing you've done effects regular dom methods - trincot's mutation observer is the way to go - read the documentation and have a go yourself - note, wont work in IE10 or earlier, and there's the prefix requirement for safari

Comment: I will post an answer with the use of that, @M-S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

Demo:

```js
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        var oldDisplay = (mutation.oldValue + '').match(/display:\s*(\w*)/);
        oldDisplay = oldDisplay ? oldDisplay[1] : '';
        if (oldDisplay !== mutation.target.style.display) {
            console.log('element', mutation.target.id, 
                    'style.display=', mutation.target.style.display);
        }
    });    
});
 
// attach the observer to the elements of interest:
$('p').each(function () {
    observer.observe(this, { 
        attributes: true, 
        attributeFilter: ['style'],
        attributeOldValue: true
    });
});

// test it, by changing style.display through button clicks:
$('button').click(function() {
    $('p').toggle(); // show/hide
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1"> test this </p><button>hide/show</button>
```

Comment: wouldn't you want `attributeFilter: ['style']` to limit the observer to the style attribute? and `attributeOldValue: true` to see the `oldValue`

Comment: Yes, that would be better. I've added that just now.